# Entity Framework Profiler with EF 6.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, profiler, sharding

I am using EF Profiler together with EF 6.1.1.

Implementing this line in my Startup.cs file that hosts my Web-API (separate project):

```
HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize();
```

The project also has 2 Different contexts, 1 for The ShardManagerDb and 1 for the ShardedDb.

**Problem:**

I Run the host project an all works as expected, EF Profiler runs an i get the queries when ShardManagerContext is hit from the Web-API, the problem comes when i try to execute the Add method on the ShardedDbContext.

Is this a bug in EF 6.1.1 together with EF Profiler?
If i remove HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize(); from my Startup.cs everything works as expected.

How do i solve this without removing the EF Profiler?

**Exception message:**

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET
>   provider is installed or registered in the application config.

**Stacktrace:**

> vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory
>   factory)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`2
>   k)    vid
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver
>   r)    vid System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   vid System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0(IDbDependencyResolver
>   r)    vid System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   vid System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver
>   resolver, Object key)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection
>   connection)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
>   vid System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
>   vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext
>   context)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   vid System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   vid System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action
>   action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)    vid
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>   vid System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)    vid
>   Dexter.Data.EF.Shard.Repositories.SalonRepositoryBase`1.Add(T entity)
>   i
>   c:\Dev\GIT\Itsperfect\Dexter\Dexter.Data.EF.Shard\Repositories\SalonRepositoryBase.cs:rad
>   30    vid
>   Dexter.Data.EF.Shard.Repositories.ConvertedDataRepository.InsertSalonData(Salon
>   salon) i
>   c:\Dev\GIT\Itsperfect\Dexter\Dexter.Data.EF.Shard\Repositories\ConvertedDataRepository.cs:rad
>   19

Comment: Which version of EF Profiler are you using?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor im am using the latest version of EF profiler 2.0